# Schedule notification not working for alarm app

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification, alarm

Hello i am trying to make alram app for that i am using Schedule notification using this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/53902489 i have set time but getting nothing ,i want to set time and remind something and ring sound on the specific time

```
    scheduleNotification(at: createDate(date : 6, month : 2, hour: 17, minute: 15, year: 2019), identifierUnic: stringUUID(), body: "Notification day", titles: "Notification titles1")


      func createDate(date: Int, month : Int, hour: Int, minute: Int, year: Int)->Date {

            var components = DateComponents()
            components.hour = hour
            components.minute = minute
            components.year = year
            components.day = date
            components.month = month

            components.timeZone = .current

            let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
            return calendar.date(from: components)!
        }


   func scheduleNotification(at date: Date, identifierUnic : String, body: String, titles:String) {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in }

         var anniversary = DateComponents()
        anniversary.day = 6
        anniversary.month = 2
        anniversary.hour = 5
        anniversary.minute = 44
        anniversary.second = 0

        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: anniversary, repeats: true)
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = titles
        content.body = body
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        content.categoryIdentifier = identifierUnic

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifierUnic, content: content, trigger: trigger)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(" We had an error: \(error)")
            }}
    }


      func registerLocal() {
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

            center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
                if granted {
                    print("Yay!")
                } else {
                    print("D'oh")
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try create an unique id for your request and, add your notification with this.

Here is my notification, and for me it works well

1. Create center and check for authorization

   ```
   let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
   center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) {
       (granted, error) in
   }
   ```
2. Create a content

   ```
   let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
   content.title = "Title"
   content.subtitle = "Subtitle."
   content.body = "Body"
   ```
3. Create date components

   ```
   var anniversary = DateComponents()
   anniversary.day = 1
   anniversary.month = 1
   anniversary.hour = 12
   anniversary.minute = 0
   anniversary.second = 0
   ```
4. Create a trigger

   ```
   let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: anniversary, repeats: true)
   ```
5. Create unique ID and request

   ```
   let uuid = UUID().uuidString
   let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuid, content: content, trigger: trigger)
   ```
6. Add your request to center and handle your error

   ```
   center.add(request) {
       (error) in
      //Write your handle function here..
      //print(error) for example
   }
   ```

I hope it helps...

Comment: bro still not working i dont have any error permission granted check udpated code

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what's wrong. Is there a error message prints out, or build successfully and app doesnt send a notification ?

Comment: app run successfully and there is no error and no notification on time

Comment: in request.identifier its sceheduled but trigging